# Are the values extracted by SURF descriptor a good input for neural network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, surf

As mentioned in the title, are those values good enough to train a neural network for classification tasks (2 classes)?

My objective is to try segmenting foreground and background using feature points extracted using SURF. These feature points extracted will be input into a neural network (supervised or classification).

My question is, are these values (128 or 64 gradient information) a good choice to train a NN?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data?

Comment: Have you managed to do this?
I was working on something similar, extracting Cars from a static image and I came across this question while doing my research.
If you have managed, can you share with us how you made it work? Not code but at least the theory.

Comment: Well the result for me ain't too good but it's not too bad too. I would say a 60-70% accuracy. Ignoring the false negatives, the false positive is quite low. I managed to detect most of the points on my target object, but it's not consistent enough throughout the frames in my testing video. It could work great in static image depending on your training set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, very good.

Slightly longer answer: You're relying on SURF to do what SURF does best and you're relying on the NN to classify/recognize the pattern of those inputs. That's exactly right. In reality, it always depends on the exact task at hand and if, for whatever reason, SURF doesn't pick up the features relating to the model you're building, then you'll have trouble. But in general: thumb's up.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try now. I shall leave this question open for few more days first.